# File Upload in Selected Location

Tags: files

I have file field in a content type to upload files. I have also created a drop down which has different values like folder 1, folder 2, folder 3 and so on.

I want file field to upload my files on location based on that drop down value.

for example if I have selected folder 2 in the drop down then the files should upload in folder 2

please provide some help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [File Path Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths)

> Adds the ability to use node tokens in destination paths and
>   filenames.

Comment: I have used this module which solve my problem but I little more help. Actually when I edit my content after saving that once and select different folder from select list and save it the file did not move to new location. Is there some way we can resolve this issue also ?? 2ndly it creates the folder in this location sites/default/files/folder1/banner3.jpg what if I want to create folder in sites folder or public_html folder ??